# How to authenticate an EWS MultiTenant application by using OAuth for Microsoft Personal Accounts

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices

I have a feature that accesses the user's calendar using EWS that used basic authentication.

**Switch to modern authentication using OAuth2.0**
I registered a **multitenant** application to support both organizational and personal Microsoft accounts.
[image]

I am able to successfully authenticate for organizational users but not for Microsoft personal accounts.

> Error Code: invalid_scope
> Error Description: The provided resource value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid.

**Scope**: https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All

**Authorization URL**:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fmyapp%2fAuthorization%2f%2fRedirect.aspx
&response_type=code
&response_mode=query
&prompt=login
&scope=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.office365.com%2fEWS.AccessAsUser.All
&state=6a155f24-7065-4f75-9fa9-3c1415acf7dd
&code_challenge=YzuKsJschRNKjuQdbJu5Q2awMmlxmT0QbPD2RI-QKn4
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

Can I access the Microsoft personal account using EWS or should I update the code to use Microsoft Graph API?

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I registered a **multitenant** application to support both Organizational and personal Microsoft accounts as below:

[image]

I added **API permissions** for that application like this:

[image]

When I tried signing in with ***organizational accounts***(ends with onmicrosoft.com), it is authenticating successfully with **`code`** in *address bar* as below:

**Authorization URL**:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=614xxx03-c5xx-xxxx-9xx8-031b2xxxxxx
&redirect_uri=https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
&response_type=code
&response_mode=query
&prompt=login
&scope=https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All
&code_challenge=Nj9YouqxxxxxxxxxxxxxxYsqlUdn1sga3CR0
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

**Response:**

[image]

But, when I tried signing in with ***personal Microsoft accounts*** (ends with outlook.com), I got same error as you like below:

[image]

> error = invalid_scope
> error_description = The provided resource value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid.

Please **note** that, EWS does not support ***personal Microsoft accounts***. So, you can only use organizational accounts to authenticate EWS.

To confirm this, please check similar scenario in ***[Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/917011/the-given-token-is-invalid-error-in-ews-oauth-auth.html)*** by Alfredo Revilla-MSFT.

Comment: What's the alternate option for personal Microsoft accounts? I am still not confident to switch to Graph API because it says the API is in Beta version https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0